# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS on a method call

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, dealloc

This is really weird in my perspective.  I've never seen anything like it.  I put all my releases in a method called `releaseMethod`.  Then in my `dealloc` and `didReceiveMemoryWarning`, I have `[self releaseMethod];`  I do this to be more object orienteted and save code because I have a lot of releases.  But, occasionally (2 out of 5 times, give or take), I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on the `releaseMethod` call in `dealloc`.  The code is below.  I didn't know it was possible to have a method call get bad access.  I understand memory management and there is no memory involved in calling a method, right?
Thanks in advance.

```
 - (void)dealloc {
     [super dealloc];
     [self releaseMethod];
 }
```

Comment: So we `dealloc` an object and then expect to be able to call messages on the deallocated object, really?

Comment: put it before the super call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you send the message `release` to an object that has already been deallocated, this is the message you will get. Check that you aren't overreleasing something in `releaseMethod`. Remember, when an object is deallocated, it will release objects that it is retaining.

You should also put `[self releaseMethod]` before you call `[super dealloc]`.

Comment: Not quite. As Joost pointed out, the problem is that `[super dealloc]` is invoked before messaging self. This is a dangerous practice.

Comment: @Justin: Agreed, but since the error happens sporadically and not consistently, he is probably also over releasing something.

Comment: I would assume exactly the opposite. An over-release would lead to consistent crashing.

Comment: @Justin: that depends on what other objects may be retaining the over-released object.

Comment: Once an object is deallocated, all subsequent messaging to that object will yield undefined behavior.

Comment: Alright, I see where you're coming from. It feels like a red herring to me, but it might prove helpful to the OP.

Comment: @bbum: Exactly. That's why the crash is inconsistent. The answer to this question is unrelated to the implementation of `releaseMethod`.

Comment: Thanks, That really helped (moving `[super dealloc]`).  The problem has been completely cleared up.

Answer (score 3):

Put your [super dealloc] at the end of the dealloc so you can first cleanup things in your class before cleaning up things in the superclass (which you might depend on).